# Request Permission in Facebook iFrame Tab Page

Tags: javascript, facebook

Well, this doens't work.

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,offline_access", function(perms) {
    if (!perms) {
        document.location.href='YouNeedToAuthorize.html';
    } else {
    document.location.href='homePage.html';
    }
});
```

**FB.Connect is undefined**

Comment: It happens the same to me

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
this.FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,offline_access", function(perms) {
    if (!perms) {
        document.location.href='YouNeedToAuthorize.html';
    } else {
    document.location.href='homePage.html';
    }
});
```

Also make sure you have this towards the end of your page.

```
  <div id="FB_HiddenIFrameContainer"
       style="display:none; position:absolute; left:-100px;top:-100px; width:0; height: 0;">
    <script
    src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil","XFBML"], function(){
    FB.Facebook.init( "{{ API_KEY }}", "/fb/xd");
    FB.XdComm.Server.init("/fb/xd");
    FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent(); });
    </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: I already have this add: 
`<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 FB.init({
         appId  : '<?=$facebook->appId?>',
         status : true, // check login status
         cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
       });
</script>`

Comment: good.  try to put 'this' before FB.Connect as the example above shows.